# JPA entity relationship with itself and cascade delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have entity object which has relationship with itself in two forms:

1. entity refer to list of that entities
2. entity refer to entity (mainOrder), which is superior current enitity

Java class for order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_order")
public class ShopOrder  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "main_id",
            nullable = true)
    private ShopOrder mainOrder;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id") // I am not sure here should be id or mainOrder
    private Set<ShopOrder> subOrders = new HashSet<>();

    // some others columns, and getters and setters
}
```

Can you tell me how to ensure that entity for cascade remove? I need if some order will be removed, also will be removed its suborders (it means orders which have set that removed order as mainOrder)

Comment: It should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainOrder")`. You do a cascade remove as for any other association needing to cascade the removal: `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE`. Why don't you just test your code, and do experiments, before asking?

Comment: For that answer thanks. Problem is I am new in JPA and Hibernate, and I don't know how to use cascade feature from jpa or hibernate. Can you add answer with that please?

Comment: Then why don't you simply read the manual? That's what it's written for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mappedBy is the attribute name in the class ShopOrder that is the back reference to ShopOrder.

Cascade can be defined in the annotation attribute cascade

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mainOrder", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<ShopOrder> subOrders = new HashSet<>();
```

Read more about Cascading in the Hibernate manual:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade